# MySQL database characters - Is there a difference between INSERT methods?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, set, character

I have a MySQL database with ~250 texts, each translated into 9 different languages. They are all inserted there by hired freelancers using a translation system (through INSERT commands in php scripts).

When looking at the texts in phpmyadmin, the characters look weird, for instance, an arabic text could look like:

???³?¬???„ ?¯?®?ˆ?„ ?§?„?ˆ?ƒ?„?§??

a hindi text could look like:

à¤?à¤œà¥‡à¤‚à¤? à¤²à¥‰à¤— à¤‡à¤¨

and so forward. However, when displayed on the website, it would look correct.

Today I had to do a backup recovery of the database (I'm using myRepono), and after the recovery was done, the texts looked exactly the same (scrambled) in phpmyadmin. However, now the same scrambled characters are also displayed on the website.

Why is this happening, when the phpmyadmin texts look exactly the same? And what can I do? Help very much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this a question for myRepono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phpMyAdmin wiki has a [pretty in-depth explanation](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data) of various character encoding issues (as well as tips on how to fix it).

I have no idea what MyRepono might have done, though.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I realized the scrambled text is impossible to recreate because most of the special characters were replaced by question marks, and therefore irreversible.